# Why is useEffect being triggered without dependency change when working with modals?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble working with useEffect to fetch comments when using a modal. I have a PostMain component that is displayed inside a modal, as seen below. Inside this, there is a CommentsList child component that fetches comments left under the post from the server. I have created a custom hook to handle this, as seen below. The problem I'm facing is whenever I exit the modal, then reopen it, useEffect is triggered even though its dependencies (pageNumber, postId) haven't changed. A server request similar to the initial one is sent, with the same comments being added to the list, as seen in the screenshots below. Obviously, this is not ideal. So, what am I doing wrong? How do I fix this?

**Fetch Comments Custom Hook**

```
    import { useEffect } from 'react';
    import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

    import { fetchComments } from '../store/comments/actions';

    function useFetchComments(pageNumber, commentsPerRequest = 5, postId) {
      const { error, hasMoreComments, isLoading, commentList } = useSelector(
        ({ comments }) => ({
          error: comments.error,
          hasMoreComments: comments.hasMoreComments,
          isLoading: comments.isLoading,
          commentList: comments.commentList,
        })
      );

      const currentCommentListLength = commentList.length || 0;

      const dispatch = useDispatch();

      useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchComments(pageNumber, commentsPerRequest, currentCommentListLength, postId));

        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
      }, [pageNumber, postId]);

      return {
        error,
        hasMoreComments,
        isLoading,
        commentList,
      };
    }

    export default useFetchComments;
```

**Post Component**

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
    import { Image, Modal } from 'semantic-ui-react';

    import CommentForm from '../../forms/comment';
    import CommentList from '../../shared/comment-list';

    function PostMain({ post }) {
      const { isLoggedIn } = useSelector(({ auth }) => ({
        isLoggedIn: auth.isLoggedIn,
      }));

      return (
        <Modal size="tiny" trigger={<Image src={post.url} />}>
          <Modal.Content>
            <div>
              <Image src={post.url} />
              <CommentList postId={post._id} />
              {isLoggedIn && (
                <CommentForm postId={post._id} />
              )}
            </div>
          </Modal.Content>
        </Modal>
      );
    }

    export default PostMain;
```

**Comment List Component**

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';

    import { useFetchComments } from '../../../hooks';

    function CommentList({ postId }) {
      const COMMENTS_PER_REQUEST = 5;

      const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);
      const { error, isLoading, commentList, hasMoreComments } = useFetchComments(
        pageNumber,
        COMMENTS_PER_REQUEST,
        postId
      );

      const handleFetchMoreComments = () => {
        setPageNumber((previousNumber) => previousNumber + 1);
      };

      return (
        <div>
          <div>
            {commentList.map((comment) => (
              <div key={comment._id}>{comment.body}</div>
            ))}
            {hasMoreComments && (
              <p onClick={handleFetchMoreComments}>View More</p>
            )}
          </div>
          {isLoading && <p>Loading...</p>}
          {error && <p>{JSON.stringify(error)}</p>}
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default CommentList;
```

**First instance of opening modal**

[image]

**Second instance of opening modal**

[image]

Comment: Very likely because component got unmounted. You can add another effect hook to verify. `useEffect(() => (() => console.log("unmounted")), [])`.

Comment: If that comp is unmounted then re-mounted, then it’s just normal the effect hook re-run.

Comment: Like others pointed. Your model is mounted then unmounted then re-mounted. Possible solution to prevent it is to lift your effect up and pass it as a prop to modal.

Comment: @hackape Yup! That's pretty much what is happening.

Comment: @AtinSingh Exactly! Will do just that. Thanks for the suggestion.